# What's the meaning of the Ubuntu logo? Where does it come from?

Tags: branding, history-of-ubuntu

What's the meaning of the Ubuntu logo? Where does this logo come from?

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Ubuntu means "an ethic or humanist philosophy focusing on people's allegiances and relations with each other". And  the logo is a graphical representation of 3 people holding their arms out, making a circle. See these 2 images:

[image: im1]
[image: new]

So the logo is perfectly describing the word Ubuntu.

Comment: I also think, the logo are 3 people, holding their hands. ubuntu means humanity.

Comment: This is also why the logo is often referred to as "The Circle Of Friends".

Answer (score 10):

The Ubuntu logo is called "**circle of friends**", read following reference may be will interest to you.

*- http://www.ubuntubuzz.com/2011/08/20-thing-should-know-about-ubuntu.html*

Answer (score -3):

I always thought the Ubuntu logo looked like the circular bit in the center of a [laptop's CD reader](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VaxF0.jpg), a reference to Ubuntu's Live CD distribution.