# Is the Ubuntu logo an African symbol?

Tags: logo

I understand the logo is meant to represent the Zulu philosophy of Ubuntu, but is the logo an African symbol??

Comment: I think it's a picture of people holding hands/working together.

Comment: here you go: http://askubuntu.com/questions/42724/whats-the-meaning-of-the-ubuntu-logo-where-does-it-come-from/42725#42725

Answer (score 2):

I think, many years ago, the origional logo represents a circle of friends.

> It is made up of a custom designed font (wordmark), carefully spaced with a re-drawn ‘Circle of Friends’ placed within a roundel.

http://design.ubuntu.com/brand/ubuntu-logo

But no, it is not an African logo.

You can review the current philosophy here

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Brand

http://design.ubuntu.com/