# isn't the ubuntu logo related in any way to the The Pax Cultura emblem?

Tags: logo, emblem

### Pax Cultura Emblem in relation to the ubuntu logo.

[image: link]

---

If you place the outer circles of the ubuntu logo inside the bigger circle you are going to have a pretty similar logo.

Comment: What about this http://www.clipartbest.com/cliparts/9ip/RkA/9ipRkApiE.jpeg ...  3 circles a borrowed logo does not make.

Answer (score 3):

No.

Plain and simple, that's the answer - their logo has only a visual relation to the Ubuntu logo.

While I do agree with you that they look similar, the Ubuntu logo, [commonly referred to as the *Circle of Friends*](https://askubuntu.com/questions/42724/whats-the-meaning-of-the-ubuntu-logo-where-does-it-come-from) is supposed to represent the community and the meaning of the word "Ubuntu".

From the [About Ubuntu page](http://www.ubuntu.com/about/about-ubuntu):

> Ubuntu is an ancient African word meaning 'humanity to others'. It
> also means 'I am what I am because of who we all are'.

Thus, this leads to the "Circle of Friends" name for the logo, because Ubuntu means "I am what I am because of who we all are".

About the "Circle of Friends" logo name - from the [Ubuntu Design page for the Logo](http://design.ubuntu.com/brand/ubuntu-logo):

> ### The Circle of Friends
>
> The Ubuntu logo is made up of the Ubuntu wordmark and the Ubuntu
> symbol. This symbol is called the ‘Circle of Friends’.

From a [wikipedia page that talks about Peace symbols (including the Pax Cultura emblem)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peace_symbols#Roerich.27s_peace_banner):

> ... Roerich came across numerous later examples in
> various parts of the world, and knew that it represented a deep and
> sophisticated understanding of the triune nature of existence...

Basically, although they *look* similar, they have no actual relation.